# How to slide down with three different classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's very clear that my script is working for one class. But it's not working for several classes which have the same intention. I try to put from div (#panel) into class (.panel) because I'm using several classes. But it's still not working. Does any of you have solution for this? Here is my jsfiddle, so you are able to look what is the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/2FPZE/1/

This is html

```
    <div class="more-link"> more </div>
        <div class="panel">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
              </div>

<div class="more-link"> more </div>
        <div class="panel">
              <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
              </div>
```

This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".more-link").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideDown("slow");
        $(".more-link").remove();
      });
    });
```

And my css

```
.panel {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me in your JSFiddle. Don't forget to include jQuery in your fiddle example though.

Comment: Yes you miss that including jQuery. else working example with respect to code.

Comment: @AlecMoore It is true the jQuery isnt loaded, but it is not working since he has 2 links and want to expand 1 div on click and not both.

Comment: Hey sorry, i didnt test it out and i forgot to load jquery in my JSFiddle. I usually try out in my localhost. I put JSFiddle just in case you guys all understand. Thank you very much. It's working for me now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to target the `.panel` relative to the clicked `.more-link`.

In the click event, `this == .more-link`.

So you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".more-link").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".panel").slideDown("slow")
        .end().remove();
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2FPZE/5/

---

**[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**

**[.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/)**

### Note

This code will work for you current DOM. But if you insert something between the link and the text, you'll need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

How did you test it on JSFiddle? 1st off you didn't even set the JQuery Framwork

See, Nothing is selected then how do you expect to fire the event?

[image]

This code will work for both links

```
    $(".more-link").click(function () {
       $(".panel").slideDown("slow");
       $(".more-link").remove();
    });
```

Keep in mind, Don't include `$(document).ready(function () {});` in JSFiddle no need to include

Comment: I forgot to load jquery framework, i usually try out in my localhost. Thanks for that information, i'll note that down. :)